# Angular : How to define routes on the level of features-module ? So that requirement given in description is fulfilled

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app module which contains multiple feature-modules , each feature module have its feature.component files as well as other components on its level (Features can have multiple nested features).

I want to nest the routes as well , right now i have just added child routes per module and imported the same hierarchically into the *app.routing.ts* (Root).

What i want is , that at each feature-module level its corresponding component (feature.component) having `<router-outlet>` should be also plugged in into its parent's feature.component.

Is this even possible ?

Right now as i am handling routing at the app level itself , hence whatever leaf component that is defined gets rendered inside the `<router-outlet>` of the App and not its (leaf's) parent feature.component. I want it to be plugged in hierarchically .

Comment: Basically what you are looking for is a tree structure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kJXf.gif) using components as the nodes, the route as the path and embedding each component on the path into each other until you reach the last node on the path?

Comment: Yes , exactly . I want them (router-outler) of respective components of a module in a tree structure .